# How to extract the dominant frequency from the audio WAV file using numpy

Tags: fft, python, wave

So, I recorded [this audio](https://file.io/download/hMUuJLeQ3kLm) on my phone while I was running a tone generator on my PC at a frequency of 13Khz, now I want to extract this frequency which is dominant from the recorded `WAV` file.

So, far I tried to read the wav file using `scipy` and then I tried to calculate `FFT` to get the frequency spectrum

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samplerate, data = wavfile.read("13khz.wav")
print(f"Sample rate: {samplerate}")

length = data.shape[0] / samplerate
print(f"length = {length}s")

fft_data = np.fft.fft(data)
```

Now, I want to extract the dominant frequency, 13 Khz in this case. How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it after searching on lot of GitHub repositories

````
def extract_peak_frequency(data, sampling_rate):
    fft_data = np.fft.fft(data)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data))
    
    peak_coefficient = np.argmax(np.abs(fft_data))
    peak_freq = freqs[peak_coefficient]
    
    return abs(peak_freq * sampling_rate)
```
````

Comment: Best to select this as the answer, then!